# How simple entity class (POCO) can be mocked with Moq?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I need to test simple class like this:

```
public class SomeEntity {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And I want to write test using mock of this class objects like this:

```
var someMock = new Moq.Mock<SomeEntity>();

someMock.SetupGet(x => x.Id).Returns(12345678);
someMock.SetupGet(x => x.Name).Returns(It.IsIn(someList));
```

As you know Moq framework require interface or virtual methods to create proxy object. So my **question is**: how can I mock my entity class ***without*** implementing interface or marking properties with virtual?

UPDATE: what is the most desired result of all this is to substitute moq object to my unit test with multiple possible combinations of properties.

UPDATE 2: it looks like I don't need to mock my entity class, I just need to iterate via all possible combinations using `It.IsIn(someList)`:

```
var someEntity = new SomeEntity {
  Id = 12345678,
  Name = It.IsIn(someList)
}
```

Comment: Mock behavior, not properties...

Comment: Please see my update

Comment: You want to run the same test with different instances of SomeEntity, that has different names? I.e., all names in *someList*?

Comment: Agree with others here, there is no reason to mock a behavior-free object--here, what appears to be a DTO.  Either you need a better understanding of when/how to use object-mocking, or your code example is not sufficient.

Comment: @DenisEfimov what benefit are you trying to get via using a mock here? A logic free entity doesn't especially need mocking

Comment: Who remove recent comment about using It.IsIn without mocking? Make this answer and I will choose it. It is what I need. Could you explain how to make it iterate through its values? I will update my question

Comment: @DenisEfimov if your goal is to write a parameterized test, look at the test case feature from Nunit http://nunit.org/index.php?p=testCase&r=2.5

Comment: Not really, I don't want to create all variants. I need to update original question to make it more clear

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You wouldn't need to mock this to be able to test with it.

You should be able to test with `SomeEntity` in its current state directly (and test it itself but testing auto properties seems like a waste of effort).

If you create an interface of `ISomeEntity` that `SomeEntity` implements then you would be able to mock that inside anything that consumes it. Then you would be able to test the behavior of methods that an `ISomeEntity` is passed into.

As you've said Moq requires it to be an interface or virtual methods to work on.

```
public class SomeEntity : ISomeEntity {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}

public interface ISomeEntity {
  int Id { get; set; }
  string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then

```
var someMock = new Mock<ISomeEntity>();

someMock.SetupGet(x => x.Id).Returns(12345678);
someMock.SetupGet(x => x.Name).Returns(It.IsIn(someList));

var result = somethingelse.Act(someMock.Obect);
```

If your object is as logic free as in the example then there is no need to go to Mock

```
var item = new SomeEntity();

item .Id = 12345678;
item .Name = "some name";

var result = somethingelse.Act(item);
```

What benefit are you trying to get via using a mock here? If you are trying to run through the list and verfify for each item in it, It.IsIn won't do that (even attached to a mock) all it will check is that the value assigned to the mock is in the list of allowed values.

This breaks the single assert for each test maxim but, I think this is what you want:

```
var item = new SomeEntity();

foreach (var name in someList)
{
  item .Id = 12345678;
  item .Name = name ;

  var result = somethingelse.Act(item);
  // Assert
}
```

Comment: I don't need to test it, i need to moq it to test other classes. As I accented in my question I am looking for way without interface

Comment: @DenisEfimov it may help if you add why you cant use an interface to the question?

Comment: Because there are many of POCO objects and I don't want to clog projects with many interfaces.

Comment: Better before edit--until reason is given, better to lead with "you don't need mocking here".

Comment: I just have read description of my question. Sorry, I need to ask new question, and mark your answer as correct. Thanks you for your time

Comment: the only concrete class that should be instantiated in the test class is class under test, so it is understandable why OP wants to find a way that will allow him to mock these objects.